# Visual Basic Console application only loops once

Tags: vb.net, loops, console, while-loop

new to everything here, i was messing around with VB 2012 when i found out my program only loops once.
Help would be appreciated.

```
Module Module1
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Sub Main()
        While i < 3
            i = i + 1
            Console.WriteLine(i)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End While
        End
    End Sub
End Module
```

EDIT:
Yeah, the people here are right, with that code it is impossible, so i screwed around a bit more and came up with a solution

```
Module Module1
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Sub Main()
        While i < 3
            i = i + 1
            Console.WriteLine(i)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Impossible with the code above. Do you press return after the first loop? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why have you put extra `End`? Are you sure that's not the culprit.

```
While i < 3
    i = i + 1
    Console.WriteLine(i)
    Console.ReadLine()
End While
End  <-- not required.
```

Comment: ... how do you post text with a new line? i cant start a new line.

Comment: @user1932140 Comments are not a good place to put multiple lines of code.  If you need to do so, add it to your question.